# How to get the order number of same record if the object is data.frame?

Tags: r

If the object is a vector, i can get  the  order of the same record  with the following method:

```
 > serial <- c("df12", "cv22", "ca11", "he22", "jj32", "sq11", "cv22")
 > which(serial%in%serial[duplicated(serial)])
 [1] 2 7
```

What can i do if the object is a data.frame?

```
  which(iris%in%iris[duplicated(iris)])
 Error in `[.data.frame`(iris, duplicated(iris)) : 
   undefined columns selected


 > which(duplicated(iris))
 [1] 143
 > iris[143,]
 Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
 143 5.8 2.7 5.1 1.9 virginica
 > iris[which(iris[,1]==5.8),]
 Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
 15 5.8 4.0 1.2 0.2 setosa
 68 5.8 2.7 4.1 1.0 versicolor
 83 5.8 2.7 3.9 1.2 versicolor
 93 5.8 2.6 4.0 1.2 versicolor
 102 5.8 2.7 5.1 1.9 virginica
 115 5.8 2.8 5.1 2.4 virginica
 143 5.8 2.7 5.1 1.9 virginica
```

The order of the same record are  102 and  143,how can i get that with a line of  R  command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`duplicated` has a `fromLast` argument, so you can try something like:

```
unique(c(which(duplicated(iris, fromLast=TRUE)), which(duplicated(iris))))
# [1] 102 143
```

The `unique` is there in case there are multiple duplicates:

```
serial <- c("df12", "cv22", "ca11", "he22", "jj32", 
            "sq11", "cv22", "cv22", "cv22")
unique(c(which(duplicated(serial, fromLast=TRUE)), 
         which(duplicated(serial))))
# [1] 2 7 8 9
```

---

If you wanted to extract the rows themselves, the construct is a bit simpler since we don't need `which`:

```
iris[duplicated(iris, fromLast=TRUE) | duplicated(iris), ]
#     Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
# 102          5.8         2.7          5.1         1.9 virginica
# 143          5.8         2.7          5.1         1.9 virginica
```